# Dell Latitude E6440 Laptop and Dual Monitor not recognized in Xubuntu 14.05

Tags: ubuntu, laptop, multiple-monitors, xubuntu, dell-latitude

I have a Dell Latitude Laptop E6440. The laptop have two interfaces, VGA and HDMI. I connect an external monitor to the VGA port, but when I ran the xfce4-display-settings I see only one monitor (the laptop one ofcourse).

How can I make it to recognize the second monitor ?
I already tried booting when it is connected. Still no help.

Here is some info:

```
I am using Xubuntu 14.04:
Linux 3.13.0-30-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jun 9 22:45:01 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have a dual graphic adapter:
One is:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

Second one is:

```
01:00.0 Display controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun XT [Radeon HD 8670A/8670M/8690M]
```

xrandr says:

```
xxx@dellorian:~$ xrandr 
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1600 x 900, current 1600 x 900, maximum 1600 x 900
default connected 1600x900+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1600x900       77.0*
```

Any help ?
10x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the nomodeset in the grub that prevented it